# Formatting dates in an array

Tags: php

I have an array which has changing key depending on the table and it can also have custom fields added.  I want to be able to identify if the array contains any values that are dates and then format the date.

I have used two examples here, but they keys could be anything and the dates could be including date and/or time.  The language I am using in my app is PHP5.5.

Any ideas?

```
Array
([0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [filename] => 1051404995566.png
        [createdby] => 1
        [createddate] => 2014-07-10 13:32:46
        [enddate] => 2014-07-10
    )
[1] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [filename] => 1561404995587.png
        [createdby] => 1
        [createddate] => 2014-07-10 13:33:07
        [enddate] => 2014-08-01
    )
)
```

Comment: can always pull the table schema from db and use that to determine what keys need formatting

Comment: It's going to be resource consuming, but you have no other choice I guess but to parse the entire array, and check every key-value pair. Evaluate the values with a preg_match function, looking for "nnnn-nn-nn", where "n" stands for number, using a regex syntax.

Comment: @charlietfl - assuming the dates, and dates+time have originally being inserted in proper DATE and DATETIME columns, which is not sure, otherwise I don't think the question would have been posted.

Comment: @charlietfl I like that idea.  I do pull the columns names from another table so I could just add type to that query.  I think that is a solution that will work.

Comment: You could check for date with date_parse (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) and checkdate (http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Comment: @Bonatoc let OP determine that. It was posted as a comment,not an answer. If it's not applicable, so be it

Comment: @gdahl I am actually using this method in my app already, but only on a single row, which is why I thought I would do the same on the larger array.  Problem I have is the resource that would be used to look through a larger 10K dataset and make the mod.  I think I am going to have to try and make it at the MySQL end.

Comment: @Bonatoc I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do that and there was some function or method that existed that I was not aware of...

Comment: If you have access to the DB, then charlietfl is right : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php

Comment: @charlietfl - that is now the working solution.  Thanks.